# Why does this way to get a http client fails?

Tags: python

```
def get_client():
    with CoreClient(timeout=60000, memory='8G') as client:
        return client



class RequestClient(object):
      def __init__(self, nlp):
         self.client = get_client()
         ...

      def __call__(self, text):
         if text:
            with CoreNLPClient(timeout=60000, memory='8G') as client:
                doc = client.annotate(text, output_format='json')
         // OR 
            client = get_client()
            doc = client.annotate(text, output_format='json')

    ....
```

The code above is supposed to create a http client to post requests to the server. However, when I used the way below, it gave a timeout error:

```
client = get_client()
# submit the request to the server
doc = client.annotate(text, output_format='json')
```

However, if I get rid of the 'get client()' method, and directly use the code as the following, it works fine:

```
with CoreClient(timeout=60000, memory='8G') as client:
  # submit the request to the server
  doc = client.annotate(text, output_format='json')
```

Why does the 1st way of obtaining a client object failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the `with` statement. From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html):

> The 'with' statement is a new control-flow structure whose basic
>   structure is:
>
> ```
> with expression [as variable]:
>   with-block
> ```
>
> The expression is evaluated, and it should result in an object that supports the context management protocol (that is, has
>   **enter**() and **exit**() methods.
>
> After execution of the with-block is finished, the object's **exit**()
>   method is called, even if the block raised an exception, and can
>   therefore run clean-up code.

For example, in this code snippet:

```
with open('/etc/passwd', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    print line
    ... more processing code ...
```

After this statement has executed, the file object in f will have been automatically closed, even if the for loop raised an exception part-way through the block. If you try to return `f` from this like here :

```
def f():
  with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    return f
```

it will return a closed file, which would forbid any operation on it.

```
get_file = f()
get_file.readlines()
```

giving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Similar thing happens with your `CoreClient` object, which gets closed after the `with` statement finished executing, thus returning a closed object upon which no further operations can be performed.

Comment: Jarvis, that makes sense. I edited my code and make it more clear. The reason I wanted to use get_client() is because I want to put it in the init method, instead of the call method. If it's in the call method, it would have to be created for every request made by user. Right?

Comment: Yes, it would have to created for every request made.

Comment: Then how to solve the problem above? How to put the creation of CoreClient in the __init__ function? If I don't use with statement for the creation, I need to close it. How to close the client?

Comment: In your `__init__` method, doing `self.client = CoreClient(timeout=60000, memory='8G')` doesn't work? I guess you can define  `__del__` (destructor) containing the logic/code to close the CoreClient object, then do `del obj` where `obj` is the instance of class `RequestClient` at the end after you are done but that's mostly not necessary since Python handles garbage collection automatically.

Comment: It needs to be closed properly, since internally CoreClient creates a post request. After the 'annotate' method is called, it needs to be closed, similar to open and close a file.

Comment: I would also suggest you to ask a new question asking about how to close `CoreClient` object since what you are asking seems to have diverted from the original topic.

Comment: If the `CoreClient` object is closed after calling the annotate method once, wouldn't all the subsequent calls to the `__call__` method fail, unless you re-instantiate the `RequestClient` class? This is same as creating a new client inside the `__call__` method each time, and I guess this is not bad since `with` handles the clean-up operation properly.